# How to Iterate through a nested JSON array in amcharts tooltip HTML

Tags: javascript, arrays, amcharts

I have a data variable with following JSON

```
var data = [

        {
            "district": "Karachi West",
            "visits": 13223,
            "distSubParts": [
           {
                "name": "ABC",
                "svisits": 212
            },
            {
                "name": "ZXA",
                "svisits": 1323
            }
            ]


        },
{
            "district": "Quetta South",
            "visits": 234232,
            "distSubParts": [
           {
                "name": "GGG",
                "svisits": 234
            },
            {
                "name": "RRR",
                "svisits": 234432
            }
            ]


        },



    ];
```

and AMCharts Series HTML as

```
series.tooltipHTML = `<center><strong> {district}</strong></center>
                            <hr />
                            <table>
                            <tr>
                              <th align="left">Name</th>
                              <td>{distSubParts.name}</td>
                            </tr>
                            <tr>
                              <th align="left">Visits</th>
                              <td>{distSubParts.svisits}</td>
                            </tr>
                            </table>
                           `;
```

Now when I see tooltip it is like the image below showing nothing of distSubParts nested array

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kxLTc.jpg

How Could I iterate through the distSubParts nested array and show it in AMCharts tooltip?

I have read AMCharts Docs [AMCharts Tooltip](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/series/#Tooltip_contents) but could not find a way to iterate through nested array

Answer (score 6, accepted):

amCharts doesn't format nested data arrays. The [guide on data arrays](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/data/#Array_of_data_items), [the guide on using string formatting & data placeholders](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/formatters/formatting-strings/#Data_placeholders), and all the demos use flat arrays.

To go beyond what's built-in, use an [adapter](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/adapters/) for the `tooltipHTML` property and manually iterate over the nested array there. Keep the first part of the string that's already supported, this will allow the tooltip to trigger and the adapter for the property with it as well. Since you're using `series.tooltipHTML` I presume you have the [chart cursor](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/concepts/chart-cursor/) enabled. In this case the `target` argument for the adapter will always return the series, it may not be clear how to acquire the currently-hovered column's data at this point. To do so just refer to the series' `tooltipDataItem` property. The data, if any, will be within its `dataContext` property. So your code could look something like this:

```js
// Set a tooltipHTML so the adapter can trigger
series.tooltipHTML = `<center><strong> {district}</strong></center>
<hr />`;

// Use an adapter to iterate through the nested array and provide formatted HTML
series.adapter.add("tooltipHTML", function(html, target) {
  if (
    target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext &&
    target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext.distSubParts &&
    target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext.distSubParts.length
  ) {
    var nameCells, svisitsCells;
    nameCells = "";
    svisitsCells = "";
    target.tooltipDataItem.dataContext.distSubParts.forEach(part => {
      nameCells += `<td>${part.name}</td>`;
      svisitsCells += `<td>${part.svisits}</td>`;
    });
    html += `<table>
    <tr>
      <th align="left">Name</th>
      ${nameCells}
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th align="left">Visits</th>
      ${svisitsCells}
    </tr>
    </table>`;
  }
  return html;
});
```

Here's the above in a demo:

https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/9acac2b5b0fcb105c8bf4ed29767430d

Answer (score 1):

Using map and join should do the job.

```
var series = { tooltipHTML: ''};
var data = {
      "district": "Karachi West",
      "visits": 13223,
      "distSubParts": [
       {
          "name": "ABC",
          "svisits": 212
       },
       {
           "name": "ZXA",
            "svisits": 1323
        }
         ]
   };


var distSubParts = data.distSubParts.map(function(item){ 
                return "<tr><th align=\"left\">Name</th>" +
                       "<td>" + item .name + "</td></tr>" +
                       "<tr><th align=\"left\">Visits</th>" +
                        "<td>" + item.svisits +" </td></tr>"    
                            }).join(' ')

series.tooltipHTML = `<center><strong> {district}</strong></center>
                            <hr />
                            <table>` +
                             distSubParts +
                            `</table>`;
```

Comment: If there are many districts, I will get all distSubParts for every district tooltip!
Basically the the AMCharts automatically iterates but how does it iterate through nested array is the question!